# What happens in the stack when recursion call with parameter took place?

Tags: c++

Dealing with a case where an infinite recursion is created. In the function a long string is passed as parameter. Of course this will cause a stack overflow. I am just wondering how the stack behaves to recursive call with parameters. Does it just put the parameter into the stack every recursion?

Comment: Yes, it does. Where else would it put it?

Comment: There's no difference between recursive calls and any other call. All parameters are normally put on the stack.

Comment: The stack frames are just bigger so you get to debug your mistake quicker :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without understanding exactly which compiler and what argument, it's hard to say for sure.

Arguments may be either on the stack or in registers (but most likely registers will then need saving inside the call, before the next call). Other things can use up stack-space too.

Most modern systems will also add alignment to ensure the stack is aligned to X bytes (16 or 32, typically), and for example MS Compiler will also, in debug mode, add extra "check for overwriting outside your variables" padding.

And of course, the function call will need a return address, and although some processors can store the return address in a register, that register will need to be saved. There may also need to be a "frame-pointer" to track where local variables are, and of course if the function has local variables, those would also go on the stack for each iteration.

If the code is complex enough [which doesn't NECESSARILY mean particularly complex], the compiler may need to use registers that it has to save and restore via the stack.

On the other extreme, some compilers will change "tail recursion" to a simple loop.

In short, LOTS of factors affect this, and it's close to impossible to say for sure what actually happens without code, compiler and compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

> I am just wondering how the stack behaves to recursive call with
>   parameters. Does it just put the parameter into the stack every
>   recursion?

There is usually no "behaviour" difference.

A recursive call (with one or more parameters) in unoptimized code of a recursive function is handled the same as any other function (or method) call with the same parameters.

In properly constructed tail recursion, I have witnessed (and can probably find an example) where the compiler can optimize away the call/return. The parameter push and jump and return are collapsed to a loop.

It can be challenging to compare highly optimized recursion to a highly optimized non-recursion code.